# Oracle ORA-00907: отсутствует правая скобка

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, sqldeveloper

```
create table listener
(
    id_listener int generated by default as identity,
    constraint pk_listener primary key (id_listener),
    first_name_listener varchar(128) not null,
    second_name_listener varchar(128) not null,
    third_name_listener varchar(128) null default ('-'),
    series_passport_listener varchar(256) not null,
    constraint ch_series_passport_listener check(regexp_like(series_passport_listener, '[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}')),
    num_passport_listener varchar(256) not null,
    constraint ch_num_passport_listener check(regexp_like(num_passport_listener, '[0-9]{6}')),
    issued_by varchar(256) not null,
    num_phone_listener varchar(256) not null,
    constraint ch_num_phone_listener check(regexp_like(num_phone_listener, '%7[0-9]{10}'))
);
```

Comment: ```third_name_listener varchar(128) null default ('-'),``` - убери скобки вокруг дефолтного значения.

Comment: скобки нужны, ругается на by default as identity

Comment: а вобще в любой среде разработки под оракл при ошибке курсор будет на месте, где ошибка случилась стоять

Answer (score -1):

third_name_listener varchar(128) default ('-') null ,

- ограничения, в том числе  null/not null ДОЛЖНЫ следовать после описания данных, в том числе значения по умолчанию

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]